# Limit targets for org-refile in narrowed/indirect buffers

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to limit the targets that are offered for `org-refile` to the currently visible sub-tree in a buffer that has been created with `org-tree-to-indirect` or `org-narrow-to-subtree`

The goal is to make re-organizing entries easier in a file with several large sub-trees.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, alas. Setting `org-refile-targets` to something like `((nil . (:maxlevel . 5)))` will make sure you're only offered targets from the original buffer, but both the indirect buffer and the narrowed view source their completion headings from the source buffer, alas.

If you haven't already changed the value of `org-refile-targets`, then the configuration I mention above will be very much like the default of `((nil . (:level . 1)))`.

My best suggestion, frankly, is `helm` -- perhaps you are already using it? With helm fuzzy-matching, I find it very fast to narrow my subtree selection to a given path, even with a large number of large subtrees available.

Comment: No I haven't used helm yet, but I use ido (with flex matching) and just noticed that I can also activate that for `org-refile` using `org-completion-use-ido`. Do you know if Helm work fundamentally different for that purpose?

Comment: Ah, I don't use ido+flex, so I'm not totally sure -- but from what I've read, flex+ido would serve you fairly well.